# Find efficiently greatest difference between $2$ vectors from set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let us have a list of vectors in a $3$D space.

Is there a more efficient way to find the greatest difference between any two of them than combining each, computing the size of their difference, and then finding the max of it?

- Note 1: they are $3$D vectors but all lie always in the same plane if it helps.
- Note 2: additionally, I would like to know which combination of two of them formed the greatest difference.
- Note 3: by the difference, I mean the size of two vectors' subtraction $|\vec{v_i}-\vec{v_j}|$.

Comment: define "difference", use equations

Comment: Edited ... explained I hope well enough now

Comment: so the "size" is euclidean norm? L_1 norm? another L_p norm?

Comment: I don't know meaning of these norm. I mean simply the magnitude. 'np.linalg.norm()' by python. Or $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{0.5}$

Comment: This is called diameter, you can checkout, say https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218195902001006 and reference in it.

Answer (score 2):

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736290/how-to-find-two-most-distant-points). Since your points all lie on the same plane you can find it and reduce the problem to 2D, and in order to solve the problem in 2D you can find the convex hull and then check the $O(n)$ pairs of opposite points.